# DB connection stopped working in docker-compose file

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker-compose

This docker-compose file was working fine six months ago. But recently I tried to use it to test my app and received this error:

```
conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db-test" to address: Name or service not known
```

I read through some other stack overflow answers and tried adding 'restart: always' to the web service. I also tried adding a local network to the compose file, and nothing has worked. Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Here is my compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:

  # postgres database
  db-test:
    image: postgres:10.9
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=example
    volumes:
      - pg-test-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  # main redis instance, used to store available years for each organization
  redis-test:
    image: redis:5.0.4
    volumes:
    - redis-test-data:/data

  # redis cache used for caching agency pages like /agencies/salaries/
  redis_cache-test:
    image: redis:5.0.4

  # search engine
  elasticsearch-test:
    image: elasticsearch:5.6.10
    volumes:
       - elasticsearch-test-data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data

  # web app
  web-test:
    build: .
    environment:
    - DATABASE_URL=postgresql://postgres:example@db-test/postgres
    - ENVIRONMENT=development
    - REDIS_URL=redis://redis-test:6379
    - REDIS_CACHE_URL=redis://redis_cache-test:6379
    - ELASTIC_ENDPOINT=elasticsearch-test:9200
    env_file: docker.env
    depends_on:
      - db-test
      - redis-test
      - redis_cache-test
      - elasticsearch-test
    volumes:
      - .:/code

  # worker instance for processing large files in background
  worker-test:
    build: .
    command: python run-worker.py
    environment:
    - DATABASE_URL=postgresql://postgres:example@db-test/postgres
    - ENVIRONMENT=development
    - REDIS_URL=redis://redis-test:6379
    - REDIS_CACHE_URL=redis://redis_cache-test:6379
    - ELASTIC_ENDPOINT=elasticsearch-test:9200
    env_file: docker.env
    depends_on:
      - db-test
      - redis-test
    volumes:
      - .:/code

volumes:
  pg-test-data: {}
  redis-test-data: {}
  elasticsearch-test-data: {}
```

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:2.7.17
 ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
 RUN mkdir /code
 WORKDIR /code
 ADD . /code/
 ADD requirements /requirements
 RUN pip install -r /requirements/local.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by adding:

```
links:
  - db-test:db-test
```

to the web-test service.